# Can I copy the code if the project is open-source on github?

Tags: github

I am making a project and I found some github repository that is pretty similar to my project but not identicle. I can use some of there code but, I don't know that can i copy the code, **Not** the whole file but just a block of code from that file.

So my question is can I copy that code into my project which I will eventually publish?

Do I have to credit them or something?

Sorry for my bad english. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about licensing are off-topic here.  For details see [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963) and also [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. [opensource.se] or [law.se] may be suitable alternatives.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal / licensing question.

Comment: @dbc Oh sorry i didn't know about `opensource.stackexchange.com` and `law.stackexchange.com`. thanks for giving direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a licence in the repository. For example, if the author published the code under the MIT licence, you can use and don't need to give any credit.
Check the meaning of the licence on google. If no licence is specified, you can use the code.

Comment: Yes it has a MIT license, so this means that i can use the code right?

Comment: Yes, you can use the code

Comment: You're welcome. You can find more at: https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/licensing-a-repository

Comment: This answer is almost completely wrong, if we're talking about the law. "if the author published the code under the MIT licence, you can use and don't need to give any credit" is wrong - you do need to give credit, by including the license with your software. "If no licence is specified, you can use the code" is the opposite of the truth, if there's no license then the code is copyrighted and you can't use it without asking for permission, even though the author let you read it.